# Calculate the height i dp got wrong

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

The main problem here is that the parent layout is nested scroll view so the height must be wrap content
so the view is like first image

[image: screenshot]

> what I want is to make the "don't have an account? register" TextView
>   to be at the bottom of the screen  so I calculate the height of my
>   phone then the height of layout to subtract to subtract them and
>   assign the result to the top margin of textview

and here's my code

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = binding.parentConstraint.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (observer.isAlive()) {
            observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                float parentViewHeightInDP = (int) (binding.parentConstraint.getHeight() / displayMetrics.density);
                if (getContext() != null) {
                    float heightInDP = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;

                    float distanceBetweenLayoutBottomAndParenBottom =  heightInDP - parentViewHeightInDP;
                    if (distanceBetweenLayoutBottomAndParenBottom > 32) {
                        if (topMargin == 0) {
                            topMargin = 1;
                            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) binding.loginTextDontHaveAccount.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.topMargin = Math.round(distanceBetweenLayoutBottomAndParenBottom);
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                                binding.loginTextDontHaveAccount.requestLayout();                            }, 
50);
                    }
                }
```

but that the result I got

[image: the result]

> so my real question here is why there still some space here, I mean
>   the TextView should be exactly at the bottom

Comment: You can check correct answer

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest you to make NestedScrollView as a child instead of parent.
Make RelativeLayout as your parent and use layout_alignParentBottom to set TextView at bottom. Something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="?android:colorBackground"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:focusable="true">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="650dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="650dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/emailtext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColorHint="#80000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordtext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColorHint="#80000000" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/enter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Enter"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="This is my app"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/enter" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can use constraint layout. Pay attention to layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf button and layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf textview.